# upload files to gdrive using a tool but in a script

Tags: shell-script

I have almost thousand of files with `.dat` extension And I am using a tool built in go to upload it, But There is an issue as my each file is 31 GB and there a lot, So I want to make a bash script for doing this, which may work like

```
root@Ubuntu-1404-trusty-64-minimal /storage # gdrive --config "config.json" upload 7.dat
Uploading 7.dat
Uploaded 0B8RgYtlwEE1sSzJxeEhKd19PWnM at 17.7 MB/s, total 31.5 GB
```

But It need monitoring after each upload, I need to set next upload. Is there possible in any bash linux script, Which may wait for the process to be complete? and the automatically start for the next `.dat` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for f in *.dat
do
    gdrive --config "config.json" upload $f
done
```

Or a bash one-liner:

```
[mehlsec@localhost ~]$ for f in *.dat; do gdrive --config "config.json" upload $f; done
```

These will upload all .dat files in your current directory one after the other.

Comment: how to run this?

Comment: Just add that code into a file named `something.sh`, then make it executable with the command `chmod +x something.sh`. Run the script with `./something.sh` while in the directory with all the `.dat` files.

Comment: Or if you want a bash one-liner: `for f in *.dat; do gdrive --config "config.json" upload $f; done`